# I subclassed UIButton in MonoTouch but underlying ObjC class is still UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uikit

I have `BackButton` that inherits `UIButton`.
It doesn't have a xib, is pretty simple and contains some layout logic which I omit.

Here is how I declared it:

```
[Register("BackButton")]
public class BackButton : UIButton
{
    public BackButton (string text, EventHandler handler)
        : base (UIButtonType.Custom)
    {
        TouchUpInside += handler;
        SetTitle (text, UIControlState.Normal);
    }

    public BackButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }
}
```

If I use `BackButton` in another view's xib, its underlying class is seen as `BackButton`:

[image]

However, when I create an instance from code, the underlying class is just `UIButton`:

[image]

This is frustrating because I'm trying to [use UIAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12939321/458193) for this class and I need it to be the right instance.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, I had to call the parameterless `UIButton` constructor, and not the one I was calling.
Removing `: base (UIButtonType.Custom)` from constructor defnition was enough to make it work:

```
public BackButton (string text, EventHandler handler)
     // : base (UIButtonType.Custom) -- remove this line
{
    TouchUpInside += handler;
    SetTitle (text, UIControlState.Normal);
}
```

In hindsight, this makes perfect sense because `UIButton(UIButtonType)` constructor provided by MonoTouch actually calls `[UIButton buttonWithType:]`:

```
public UIButton (UIButtonType type) : base (
    Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend_int (UIButton.class_ptr,
        UIButton.selButtonWithType_, (int)type)
    ) { }
```

There is no way, I presume, for `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` to know about my custom view so it just creates a `UIButton`.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for this.  I had a button where the IntPtr constructor was working flawlessly and when I created one from code with UIButtonType it wasn't.  This makes perfect sense but I tried many things before finding your answer and having that "a ha" moment.